# Is there a command to move a cursor to a specific line when creating a new file in vim?

Tags: vim, gvim, vimrc

I am new to ubuntu. I am using vim for quite sometime now. I came across autocmd BufNewFile command to automatically add some text when a file with some particular etension is created.I have attached the pic of how it looks after that command. But I want the cursor to be in a different position rather than line 9.
[image: DEFAULT] I want the cursor to be on line 6.[image: example of what OP wants]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Just so you know, there is also [a Stack Exchange site specifically for Vi and Vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/). Of course, [make sure your question would be on-topic there](https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and please [_do not_ post an exact copy of your question there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/1081494). Your question is good here, but I wanted to let you know about that site as well.

Comment: @Algnis Please don't put a signature inside image alt text. If you don't want to create alt text that's fair enough, but please don't put incorrect information in instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to move to (for instance) line 10 in the file, you would type `:10`

You can put commands like this on the command line with `vim +10`

Comment: In this case, OP just needs to add `| :6` their `autocmd` to have the cursor be at line 6 when the autocmd completes.

Comment: It's also possible to go to a particular line (and column) py appending a ":normal" command to the command line, like:

`vim '+normal 6G10|'`

Answer (score 0):

So, let's say you are on line 9 and want to be on line 3.

You could push <kbd>k</kbd> 6 times.  Or you could type <kbd>6</kbd> <kbd>k</kbd> or you could (as suggested in the other answer) type <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>return</kbd> or you could type <kbd>3</kbd><kbd>g</kbd>.

There's a number of other combinations that would work as well.